# python generator yield for a file

Tags: python, list, file

I want to use a generator for my script but I get alwayse an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scan.py", line 56, in scan_m
    for line in ip_list:
  File "scan", line 46, in expand_ip_addr
    yield str(ip) + '\n'
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ip' referenced before assignment
```

and here is my code, what should I change? I had never used a generator before.

```
def expand_ip_addr():
    with open('ip.txt', 'r') as file_in:
            #remove blank lines
        for line in file_in:

            if '/' in str(line):
                for ip in IPNetwork(str(line)):
                    yield str(ip
            else:
                line

def scan_m(ip_list):
    i = 1
    try:
        for line in ip_list:
            # do something with the line
            i = i + 1


def main():
    ip_list = expand_ip_addr()
    scan_m(ip_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

update my mistake the else statement was wrong, sry

Comment: So what is `ip` supposed to be set to when there is no `/` in the line?

Comment: Note that your issue has nothing to do with generators; you are trying to use a variable that has no value set yet.

Comment: I didn't say you couldn't use a generator. Just that you'd have the same issue if this was not a generator function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
for line in file_in.read().replace('\n\n', '\n'):
```

and

```
else:
    yield str(ip) + '\n'
```

to

```
for line in file_in:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line: continue
```

and

```
else:
    yield line + '\n'
```

Comment: I believe you have modified the code significantly without any hint from OP.

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal I think these changes are spot on.

Comment: @HaiVu: I think so too! Critique-critique serves him right. Haahaa. Or at least ha.

Comment: @JonasByström I recognized on day later that sure "replace" is totaly wrong, but the else statement I really overlooked XD was completely sure that my generator was wrong, thanks ^^